# mod_spdy on apache not applying to all vhosts

Tags: apache, centos, spdy

I just installed the latest version of mod_spdy for apache. I have several vhosts running off of that server, all of which utilize SSL. Unfortunately, only about half of the sites indicate that spdy is working when using chrome://net-internals/#spdy. What's interesting is that the sites that work utilize self-signed certs. Any site with a CA issued cert does not appear to take advantage of spdy. There are no errors in the httpd log, so it may just be a coincidence that only the self-signed certs work.

I'm new to spdy and have never implemented it before. I simply installed the rpm and restarted apache.

For reference, I'm running CemtOS 6.5 with Apache 2.2.15. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!